# Oracle SQL Header and detail

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a header and detail style output which can output a header line, then detail lines, then a header line, then detail lines etc.

It will use two tables:

HeaderTable:

```
MAIN_NO MAIN_DESCRIPTION MAIN_CUST MAIN_NAME
1       Apple            Student   John
2       Pear             Child     Peter
3       Orange           Alien     Matt
```

DetailTable:

```
MAIN_NO PERF EVENT INFO   PREV_VALUE NEW_VALUE REV STATE MODIFIED   NOTE
1       ABC  YES   RED    12         30        0   Con   01/02/2018 FALSE
1       DEF  YES   BLUE   18         34        0   Con   01/04/2018 FALSE
2       GHI  NO    BLUE   14         38        0   UUU   01/07/2018 TRUE
2       JKL  NO    RED    11         39        0   Con   01/03/2018 FALSE
3       MNO  NO    GREEN  19         32        0   UUU   01/01/2018 TRUE
3       PQR  YES   WHITE  10         33        0   UUU   01/08/2018 TRUE
```

Desired Output:

```
MAIN_NO MAIN_DESCRIPTION MAIN_CUST MAIN_NAME
1       Apple            Student   John
1       ABC  YES   RED    12         30        0   Con   01/02/2018 FALSE
1       DEF  YES   BLUE   18         34        0   Con   01/04/2018 FALSE
2       Pear             Child     Peter
2       GHI  NO    BLUE   14         38        0   UUU   01/07/2018 TRUE
2       JKL  NO    RED    11         39        0   Con   01/03/2018 FALSE
3       Orange           Alien     Matt
3       MNO  NO    GREEN  19         32        0   UUU   01/01/2018 TRUE
3       PQR  YES   WHITE  10         33        0   UUU   01/08/2018 TRUE
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bacd0c

Current Code:

```
SELECT MAIN_NO, MAIN_DESCRIPTION, MAIN_CUST, MAIN_NAME
FROM 
(
    SELECT MAIN_NO, MAIN_DESCRIPTION, MAIN_CUST, MAIN_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, MAIN_NO rnk 
    FROM HeaderTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT MAIN_NO, PERF, EVENT, INFO, PREV_VALUE, NEW_VALUE, REV, STATE, MODIFIED,   NOTE, rnk 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT hd.*, hd.MAIN_NO || '.' || ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY hd.MAIN_NO ORDER BY hd.MAIN_NO) rnk
        FROM IFSAPP.HeaderTable h 
        INNER JOIN DetailTable hd on h.MAIN_NO= hd.MAIN_NO
    ) K     
)p 
ORDER BY rnk
```

However I am getting the error:

> ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Although I'm not even sure this will give me the output I want.

Comment: There's is at least one issue in your query :  the 2 UNIONed queries don't have the same number of columns. Normally you should get a ORA-01789 for this so you might or might not have another issue... but I dont see anything that could trigger an ORA-00909. So fix that first and retry.

Comment: This is normally done by joining the tables so each row has all data and doing the formatting in the front end.

Comment: @LoztInSpace Absolutely, but in this case it needs to be all SQL

Comment: @ThomasG added NULL's to the top union to make it have the same number of fields and still get the same error

Comment: You've modified the code in the question to fix the concatentation problem and add the nulls (which seems... odd...), [but you haven't changed the error you get now](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bacd0c/5) *8-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original ORA-00909 error is coming from `concat()`, which only takes two arguments; you have three:

```
concat(hd.MAIN_NO, '.', ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY hd.MAIN_NO ORDER BY hd.MAIN_NO))
```

You need nested calls:

```
concat(concat(hd.MAIN_NO, '.'), ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY hd.MAIN_NO ORDER BY hd.MAIN_NO)))
```

or use the `||` operator:

```
hd.MAIN_NO || '.' || ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY hd.MAIN_NO ORDER BY hd.MAIN_NO)
```

As noted in comments though, you have other issues; fixing the `concat` problem lets the "ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns" error come though instead.  (As in your modified question.) You can fix that with nulls, also also suggested in comments; but your `rnk` columns are also different types - the first branch uses the number form the table, the second forms a string - which will get "ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression".

I think you want to just treat the header as rank 0 within the `main_no`, which avoids the concatenation altogether:

```
SELECT MAIN_NO, MAIN_DESCRIPTION, MAIN_CUST, MAIN_NAME,
  PREV_VALUE, NEW_VALUE, REV, STATE, MODIFIED, NOTE
FROM (
    SELECT MAIN_NO, MAIN_DESCRIPTION, MAIN_CUST, MAIN_NAME,
        null as prev_value, null as new_value, null as rev, null as state,
        null as modified, null as note, 0 rnk
    FROM HeaderTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT hd.MAIN_NO, hd.PERF, hd.EVENT, hd.INFO,
        hd.PREV_VALUE, hd.NEW_VALUE, hd.REV, hd.STATE, hd.MODIFIED, hd.NOTE,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY hd.MAIN_NO ORDER BY hd.MAIN_NO) as rnk
    FROM HeaderTable h 
    INNER JOIN DetailTable hd on h.MAIN_NO= hd.MAIN_NO
)
ORDER BY main_no, rnk
/

   MAIN_NO MAIN_D MAIN_CU MAIN_ PREV_VALUE  NEW_VALUE        REV STA MODIFIED   NOTE
---------- ------ ------- ----- ---------- ---------- ---------- --- ---------- -----
         1 Apple  Student John
         1 ABC    YES     RED           12         30          0 Con 01/02/2018 FALSE
         1 DEF    YES     BLUE          18         34          0 Con 01/04/2018 FALSE
         2 Pear   Child   Peter
         2 GHI    NO      BLUE          14         38          0 UUU 01/07/2018 TRUE
         2 JKL    NO      RED           11         39          0 Con 01/03/2018 FALSE
         3 Orange Alien   Matt
         3 MNO    NO      GREEN         19         32          0 UUU 01/01/2018 TRUE
         3 PQR    YES     WHITE         10         33          0 UUU 01/08/2018 TRUE
```

I've removed some unnecessary subqueries too; you need one to stop `rnk` being included in the final result set.

Belatedly spotted you'd add a SQL Fiddle for the data; [here's the result for that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bacd0c/3).

You can explicitly cast the nulls to the expected data type but it shouldn't necessary; just for fun I've done that [in this db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=de61b6289bee0e06eacd9de57c3a8167), with your sample data in a CTE.

Comment: Works perfect! Just needed some slight tweaking for my dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have two times **MAIN_NO** in second select?

It looks like typo.

MAIN_NO, MAIN_DESCRIPTION, MAIN_CUST, MAIN_NAME, **MAIN_NO**

Comment: Its aliased as rnk

Comment: Even if it wasn't needed, it wouldn't cause the original error.